# How to ignore Property Getter and Setter in C# with Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, properties, roslyn

I'm enumerating through IMethodSymbols by getting GetMembers() and filtering with Linq. Only thing i can't filter out are property getters and setters methods - any suggestions?

For each property i also get a get_[PropertyName] and set_[PropertyName] Method.

```
TypeSymbol.GetMembers().Where(s => 
s.Kind == SymbolKind.Method && 
s.DeclaredAccessibility == Accessibility.Public && 
!s.IsImplicitlyDeclared && 
!s.IsVirtual))
```

I thought this would filter out the getters and setters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the symbol to `IMethodSymbol`, then you can use `MethodKind`:

```
member is IMethodSymbol method &&
(method.MethodKind == MethodKind.PropertyGet || method.MethodKind == MethodKind.PropertySet)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm now using a string filter like

```
.Name.StartsWith("get_")
```

but i hope there's a better solution.